# How to store the data in database using cakephp?

Tags: cakephp

Here is my code:

TimesheetsController.php:

```
class TimesheetsController extends AppController {

public function add()
{
  if (!empty($this->data)) {
  if ($this->Timesheet->save($this->data)) {
   $this->Session->setFlash('Your attendance has been saved.');
   $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
   }
}
}
}
```

Here is my view code

add.ctp:

```
<table id="completed">
$this->Form->create('Timesheets');
    <th>S.No</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>1</th>
    <th>2</th>
    <th>3</th>
    <th>4</th>
    <th>5</th>
    <th>6</th>
    <th>7</th>
    <th>8</th>
    <th>9</th>
    <th>10</th>
    <th>11</th>
    <th>12</th>
    <th>13</th>
    <th>14</th>
    <th>15</th>
    <th>16</th>
    <th>17</th>
    <th>18</th>
    <th>19</th>
    <th>20</th>
    <th>21</th>
    <th>22</th>
    <th>23</th>
    <th>24</th>
    <th>25</th>
    <th>26</th>
    <th>27</th>
    <th>28</th>
    <th>29</th>
    <th>30</th>
    <th>31</th>
echo '1'
$this->Form->input('id',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'hidden','label'=>false));
echo 'Karthikeyan';
$this->Form->input('1',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('2',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('3',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('4',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('5',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('6',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('7',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('8',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('9',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('10',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('11',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('12',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('13',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('14',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('15',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('16',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('17',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('18',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('19',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('20',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('21',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('22',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('23',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('24',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('25',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('26',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('27',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('28',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('29',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('30',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->input('31',array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
$this->Form->end('Save Attendance');
</table>
```

Comment: Have you created the model yet?  I highly recommend you go through the blog tutorial before setting off on your own.  http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog/blog.html

Comment: Also, I can't tell if those line breaks (`<br \>`) are in your code, or just some sort of messy copy over... but you definitely don't want them in any php... and almost none of the html needs them.

Comment: I have created a model: class Timesheet extends AppModel {}

Comment: Okay, what does your code presently do?  Are you experiencing any errors?  Have you gone through that tutorial?  Are those html line breaks (`<br \>`) actually in your code?

Comment: No, its not showing any errors. While i click 'save attendance' button the page getting loaded but the data's are not stored in database.

Comment: I gave this <br/> tag only in stack overflow not in my code.

Comment: So it's giving you the session flash saying it's been saved?  Is the app in debug mode?  No warnings or anything?

Comment: No, its not displaying the session flash and also it is not save in my database.

Comment: How to see whether my app in debug mode?

Comment: It's in the configs.  By default it's set to debug mode, so if you haven't changed it, it is.

Answer (score 0):

I'll be honest, it's hard to narrow down the specific issue in your code, there are several basic errors that could be getting you.  Here are some things to clean up and see if it helps:

- You're mixing html and php.  This is fine if you're using php tags, but you're not.  Every instance of php should be wrapped with `<?php` and `?>`.
- You're missing a terminator on at least one echo that I see.  Add that semicolon to the end (`;`)
- Your HTML structure is pretty confused.  I'd wager you're missing `<td>` tags around all those inputs.

What I'd recommend is that you spend a little bit of time going over the generals of HTML and PHP before you move on to a framework.  Once you have the hang of them, go through the CakePHP tutorials, which really help you get the hang of the framework.

Some useful links:

- HTML: http://www.w3schools.com/html/
- PHP: http://www.w3schools.com/php/
- CakePHP tutorials: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples.html (Specifically note the first)

---

That all said, whether you follow my advice or not, after making the above fixes to your code, update your question with the revised code, and with any errors or useful information you can give as to what the problems are, and I will revise my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 0):

```
Use echo $this->Form->input('Modelname.0.fieldname');
```

For example:

```
$this->Form->input('Timesheet.1.fieldname',
 array('class'=>'attendance','type'=>'text','label'=>false));
```

If you change input fields as shown in the example, then in your controller action you will get $this->data as

```
   'Timesheet' => array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'fieldname' => Field Value
    ),
    (int) 1 => array(
        'fieldname' => Field Value
    ),
    so on...
)
```

After that you have to modify your controller action as shown below:

```
 public function add(){
      if (!empty($this->data)) {
        if ($this->Timesheet->saveAll($this->data)) {
           $this->Session->setFlash('Your attendance has been saved.');
           $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        }
      }
 }
```

For more clarification see http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/form.html#field-naming-conventions

Hope this will help you!